# iis server not serving https website to a bunch of locations (dns_reset_error)

Tags: ssl, https, iis, vps, iis-8

i am having a bad issue of iis server here from one of my VPS not serving https version of website to some of my client locations. http is working fine, but when i switch to ssl version, the ssl certificate passed by server shows as expired on our clients machine.

As you can see in image below the machine in florida and a few other locations is reading the certs as expired. while some other places are working fine.

the server config is as below:

windows server 2012 R2
8 GB RAM , 2 ProcessorsIntel Xeon E5-2630 2.4 GHz 
IIS version 8.5.9600.16384

what we did to resolve this :

1. re-installing ssl
2. re-pointing and changing dns and waiting for days
3. checked iis bindings and reconfigured the same
4. restarted website
5. tried classic asp ,aspx and mvc versions as well as plain html pages in hope to achieve some result

the problem is issue is poping up for some people and not for all people out in the world.

[image: SSL Issue on VPS for some of locations/Random IIS]

Comment: Try asking on [sf]

Comment: That Chome screenshot seems to show way more than just your site's certificates as expired (including apis.google.com).  What makes you think your server is the problem and not the client's end?

Comment: because client can access all other sites fine, only those relaying from our sites https are having trouble